# Select a product that is on all interventions

Tags: sql

Hello my question is simple for some of yours ^^

I've a table product, reference, and intervention. When there is an intervention the table reference make the link between products that we need for the interventions and the intervention.

I would like to know how to do to search products that have made part of all interventions.

This are my tables :

```
--TABLE products
create table products (
 reference char(5) not null  check ( reference like 'DT___'),
 designation char(50) not null,
 price numeric (9,2) not null,
 primary key(reference) );

-- TABLE interventions

create table interventions ( 
    nointerv integer not null ,
    dateinterv date not null,
    nameresponsable char(30) not null,
    nameinterv char(30) not null,
    time float not null check ( temps !=0 AND  temps between 0 and 8),
    nocustomers integer not null ,
    nofact integer not null ,
    primary key( nointerv),
    foreign key( noclient) references customers,
    foreign key (nofacture) references facts 
);

-- TABLE replacements

create table replacements (
    reference char(5) not null check ( reference like 'DT%'),
    nointerv integer not null,
    qtereplaced smallint,
    primary key ( reference, nointerv ),
    foreign key (reference) references products,
    foreign key(nointerv) references interventions(nointerv) 
);
```

--EDIT :
This is a select from my replacement table
[image: Table replacements]

We can see in this picture that the product DT802 is used in every interventions
Thanks ;)

Comment: What do you want to mean by "all intervention"  Can you show us data sample, and expected result?

Comment: Concretely the replacement table make the links between the products that were used in the various interventions. What I want to ask is how to recover all the products that have been used at least once in each intervention

Comment: Good work in showing the table structure. Still, we'd like to see what have you tried so far, and how it didn't fit the bill.

Comment: where is table reference ?

Comment: What didn't fit the bill ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will show 1 line intervention - products.  Is this you are expecting for?

```
select interventions.nointerv, products.reference
from interventions
inner join replacements on interventions.nointerv = replacements.nointerv
inner join products on replacements.reference = products.reference;
```

This one?

```
select products.reference, products.designation
from interventions
inner join replacements on interventions.nointerv = replacements.nointerv
inner join products on replacements.reference = products.reference
group by products.reference, products.designation
having count(*) = (select count(*) from interventions);
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I would like. With the photo in my post, we can see that the product DT802 is in all interventions and I would like a request to get the products that are in all interventions. So in this example, just the product DT802

Comment: The select need to be products.reference, products.designation

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to follow.  If I interpret it as all `nointerv` in `replacements` whose `reference` contains all products, then:

```
select nointerv
from replacements r
group by nointerv
having count(distinct reference) = (select count(*) from products);
```